# Is there a better way for calculating the odds for the horserace card game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, card-games, gambling

[horserace card game in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqq4n.jpg)

Game:

1. The 4 aces ("horses") are laid face-up at one end of the table.
2. 6 cards face-up are laid ("race track") in a straight line perpendicular to the aces.
3. The race proceeds by flipping the remaining deck, & the ace matching that suit advances one step until a winner reaches the finish line (card 6).

**Question: How do you compute the odds for the horses after observing the cards on the racetrack?**

I believe I have come up with one solution that computes the probabilities of all possible winning hands, and sums them before converting them to odd which you can find [described here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-odds-for-the-horserace-betting-card-game#), although this (brute force) solution probably wouldn't scale well if we increase the number of cards, and makes me think they could be a simpler, more beautiful solution...

Comment: To be clear, what exactly is your question? Are you trying to calculate the odds for the horses *after* the 6 cards are laid face up?

Comment: @Théophile Yes, I hope to establish the odds after observing the cards on the racetrack.